# OpenGL ES multiple objects not being rendered

Tags: android, opengl-es, rendering

I am doing the following to render multiple balls move around the screen but only 1 ball is seen to appear and function. I don't know why the rest (count-1) balls are not being drawn

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
         gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);   
         gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glClientActiveTexture(DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
         gl.glLoadIdentity();
         for(int i=0;i<mParticleSystem.getParticleCount();i++){
            gl.glPushMatrix();
                  gl.glTranslatef(mParticleSystem.getPosX(i), mParticleSystem.getPosY(i), -3.0f);
                  gl.glScalef(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f);
                  gl.glColor4f(r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), 1);
                  gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);   
                  mParticleSystem.getBall(i).draw(gl);
            gl.glPopMatrix();

         }


    }
```

Here is  my void draw(GL10 gl) method

```
public void draw(GL10 gl){

gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
//  gl.glTranslatef(0.2f, 0.2f, -3.0f); 
//  gl.glScalef(size, size, 1.0f);

gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertBuff);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, points/2);
gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

}
```

I couldnt take the snapshot on my Samsung Phone but here is the emulator screenshot. In reality, the ball moves around with change in orientation and acceleration and keeps changing color randomly (due to r.nextFLoat()) . However, the other 35 balls arent even being rendered as you can see. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Aren't you rendering the same ball multiple times? Try to render only one ball (try more of them, but only one ball at a time). If only one is rendered, which one? First? Last? Random?

Comment: The `mParticleSystem` class contains an array of balls. I Iterate over each ball and set their position. Yea, so only first ball is rendered.

Comment: The code you posted does not seem to contain an error, so it is most likely an error in the code you _didn't_ post. Are you sure your getPos(i) actually returns significantly different results for each i? if you replace them by ad-hoc random values, do you still only see one ball? If you step through the debugger, do the expected values show up? If you unroll the loop for the first couple of indices, does it still break? What if you start i at a different index? Is your code sufficiently randomized, i.e. could it be the other balls show up _outside_ the screen every time?

Comment: Have you tried to execute "loadIdentity" inside the "for" loop? I think you should clear the transformations before render every object.